Why does send_video not work in my Python Telegram bot while send_animation works fine?
I'm developing a Telegram bot using the python-telegram-bot library. The bot is supposed to forward GIFs and videos to another user without watermarking the original sender's ID. While send_animation works perfectly, send_video fails to send the video. Here’s the relevant part of my code:
def forward_media(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message = update.message
    bot = context.bot
    chat_id = TARGET_USER_ID
    
    try:
        if message.animation:
            bot.send_animation(chat_id=chat_id, animation=message.animation.file_id,
                               caption=message.caption, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
            update.message.reply_text("GIF has been forwarded successfully.")
        elif message.video:
            bot.send_video(chat_id=chat_id, video=message.video.file_id,
                           caption=message.caption, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
            update.message.reply_text("Video has been forwarded successfully.")
        else:
            update.message.reply_text("Please send a GIF or video.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        update.message.reply_text("An error occurred while forwarding the media. Please try again.")

TL;DR: send_video in python-telegram-bot fails to send videos (doesn't do anything with no errors) while send_animation works fine for GIFs. Why might this be happening, and how can I fix it?

Does the reply message send? Are you able to run a test with a video you upload directly instead of the one from the message?

If the video is not being forwarded and no exceptions are caught, then I wonder if the specified condition is actually executed at all. Can you confirm your code is being executed with adding some print statement to log execution flow.

Also, another way around it I see is use the copy_message method instead of multiple cases. The copy_message method can forward any type of message without the Forwarded from tag.
It would look something like:
def forward_media(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message = update.message
    bot = context.bot
    chat_id = TARGET_USER_ID

    try:
        if message.animation or message.video:
            bot.copy_message(chat_id=chat_id, from_chat_id=message.chat_id, message_id=message.message_id)
            update.message.reply_text("Media has been forwarded successfully.")
        else:
            update.message.reply_text("Please send a GIF or video.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        update.message.reply_text("An error occurred while forwarding the media. Please try again.")

Hope this helps!
